# what is my problem trying to use google jquery ajax api

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, api

I'm trying to set up a page that uses the OpenWeatherMap (openweathermap.org) using JQuery, but I'm getting a 403 error near the start of the page.

The page starts

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="UTF-8" /><title>Weather API</title>
<script src=”https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
</head>
<body>
```

But I see in the console log:

```
Navigated to http://minkhost:7080/weather.html
14:03:55.970 weather.html:5 GET http://minkhost:7080/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9Dhttps://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9D net::ERR_ABORTED 403 (Forbidden)
14:03:55.970 weather.html:17 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Do I need to change the charset somehow? Let me know if I need to include more from the page.

Comment: Looks like you've got some bad HTML there. You've got a curly quote after `src=` and after the jQuery URL.

Comment: I'm not sure what's happening there. I'm using Notepad++ to edit files, and I noticed once you pointed that out that it's often replacing quotes with curly quotes. I would think it would know not to do that when I'm editing an .html file! I'm looking into it...

Comment: `http://minkhost:7080/%C3%A2%E2%82%AC%C2%9Dhttps://ajax.googleapis.com` something changing your urls?  Or was it the curly "?